# could not find http://www.objectdb.com/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, objectdatasource, objectdb

In eclipse when i am going to install objectDb data Source Driver like: 
help-->Install New Software...-->then i am adding 
url: http://www.objectdb.com/eclipse. it gives the error like:
 "could not find  http://www.objectdb.com/eclipse" so i am unable to getting objectDb data source inside eclipse IDE so how can i solve this problem.

Thank You....

[Attachment of screen shoot of this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeuaM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for manual installation:** Since Eclipse won't recognize the software site, you can try downloading those jars yourself and do a local installation. When you go to Install New Software -> Add, there should be an option called Archive for installing the jar files.

I've tried looking around for an Eclipse plugin for Object DB and haven't found much. Since the plugin files in the link you provided appear two years old and the link does not work with Eclipse, perhaps Object DB can be installed manually? On their website, the downloads section [here](http://www.objectdb.com/download) offers Object DB's jar files and more (and these ones are recent).

Comment: I have already install manually. it also working to store data or retrieve data but when i am going to generate a BIRT(Business Intelligence Reporting Tool) it need a data Source eclipse already contain Jdbc type(oracle,mysql etc) or like mongo db Xml data Source etc... but in that list ObjectDb is not there... i need this here because to create birt. then how to add manually if i am adding manually objectDb is not present at data Source list....

Comment: @BimalKumarDalei You could try downloading the driver files from the software site that Eclipse won't accept, then locally installing. When you try to add the site under Install New Software, there's an option for local file installation.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue that was fixed. Automatic installation should be available now.